# how to make automatic click ok button on showdialog() on c# application?

Tags: c#, button, showdialog

I'm using a windows mobile application .. exactly it's 
Microsoft.WindowsMobile.Samples.CECamera

When I capture an image a dialog form appears to tell it's successfully captured and I should click ok. 
In the code, it uses this ok click to continue saving the picture ...
Now I want this message to stop appearing. 
or any other method to make an automatic click on that ok button.

```
 if (DialogResult.OK == cameraCapture.ShowDialog())
            {
                string fileName = cameraCapture.FileName;

                // If it is a video we rename the file so that it has the user entered
                // default filename and the correct extension.
                if (cameraCapture.Mode != CameraCaptureMode.Still)
                {
                    string extension = fileName.Substring(fileName.LastIndexOf("."));
                    string directory = "";

                    if (fileName.LastIndexOf("\\") != -1)
                    {
                        directory = fileName.Substring(0, fileName.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
                    }

                    fileName = directory + this.textDefaultFileName.Text + extension;

                    System.IO.File.Move(cameraCapture.FileName, fileName);
                }

                // The method completed successfully.
                MessageBox.Show("The picture or video has been successfully captured and saved to:\n\n" + fileName,
                    this.Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
            }
        }
```

Comment: and automatic click will close the dialog?After how many seconds?

Comment: in no time .. i just want it to disappear actually it's useless .. i just will deal with blind people so he won't be able to see such message , i wanna remove it or handle it automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution for this case when i want to hide the capture dialog

```
cameraDialog.Dispose();
```

after the end of if statements

```
if (DialogResult.OK == cameraCapture.ShowDialog())
{
    //plapla
}

cameraDialog.Dispose();
```

Comment: I really don't understand why you even check if OK button was clicked if you do not care if it was clicked. and how calling Dispose method gives you what you asked for in your question which was automatic click on a button or way of not showing a dialog at all.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the line (actually, technically it's two lines) that shows the dialog from the source.

In general, trying to automatically click on buttons in your own application is a really bad idea.

Comment: i don't have the source it's showed by default when i call cameraCapture method

Comment: Then what is the code that you posted? Because there seems to be the code to show the dialog you are talking about.

Comment: the code is what should happened when i click ok on dialogue msg which is actually use less .. that's why i need to make this msg to disappear.. or be dealt with automatically.. as a blind will use the application and won't be able to see that msg.

Answer (score 1):

If it's your code, just write your own message box class that contains a timer; it'll be the best solution.

If the message box is displayed by someone other's code, you can:

1. Use [Windows Hooks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632589%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to intercept msgbox arrearing
2. Just iterate through windows list using [EnumWindows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633497%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: can you please tell me how to do that by the 1st or the 2nd option.

Comment: it's not my code it's appear by default when i call the c# method cameraCapture()
and i should press ok o complete the process

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/DLL/keyboardhook.aspx, http://developer-resource.blogspot.com/2008/07/setwindowshookex-example.html -- samples how to use hooks.

EnumWindows is much simplier, here you just get list of windows; you can find the window you need and then send WM_CLOSE to it.

Comment: unfortunately the examples are on c++ , i need any example explains how to use them in c# please .. thanks very much

Comment: You can easily use win32 in .NET: P/Invoke will help you, see http://pinvoke.net/
I think if you do what you want to do on C++, it won't be any problems to convert your code to C#.